# Orchard CMS - remove an alternative

Tags: orchardcms

I have created a shape alternative, 'List.cshtml' but don't need this.

Now that I deleted the file from the Views folder, Blog Post list throws an error trying to find view file in theme directory and list of Content items in dashboard doesn't display any items.

So how do I delete a published view alternative and have Orchard go back to using the version from the module?

Version 1.10.0

Comment: It should go back by itself. What do the logs say?

Comment: @devqon I believe it will go back by itself in VS, but if it's a deployed or compiled version of the site the theme needs to be recompiled with an app pool refresh, site restart, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to restart the site. I recommend going into IIS and recycle the app pool.

Is this a deployed version of the site? I think that is the only time it will error when you remove a view file, if you're running the source in Visual Studio it will go back up the cascade to the proper view file/location.